# How to use one component in another component vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```
<my-comp
title="title" 
craps="one->two->three"
/>

<bread :record="record"> 

data(){
return {
 record = [{title: 'name', item: 'one'}, {title: 'name', item:'two'}];
}
}
```

I wanted to use <bread component in  component under craps like this

```
<my-comp
title="title" 
craps=<bread :record="record"> 
/>
```

what is the process to use of it please guide

Thank you

Comment: where are your components defined in relation to each other (what is the file structure or are they defined in the same file)?

Comment: <my-comp> and <bread> are defined in different component using it in one component

Comment: I might use slots, but you could also pass record to `my-comp` and pass on to `<bread>` inside `my-comp`, pass the component, store record in vuex and access from `bread` in `my-comp`, or something else. There are a bunch of solutions, try one and if you run into an issue post [mcve]